# How to create a timeline component in android

Tags: android, timeline

I want to develop, a timeline kind of component, in which 24 hours are divided on x-axis with 24 laps.

At present, m trying to develop custom linear layout with 24 views for each hour and adding these in layout.. but this is not fair idea to develop.

Anyone, can suggest other method/example code, would be really appreciable.

Thanks,

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Created a new custom view for same.

Comment: hi @zoombie. Could you share your code please? I am trying to do the exact same thing as well

Comment: This is not a commit message! it's an answer it should contain some clues about the way you have solved the problem, a piece of code would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little confusing, but it sounds like you're on the right track.  Instead of adding your custom views representing the hours into the timeline layout in xml (which it sounds like you're doing) try creating your LinearLayout in code, and adding them there in a loop.  That will reduce your code duplication.

Comment: Done something similar what u have suggested, but adding multiple views will create a problem as i have timeline divided in lap of 15 mins for 24 hours. Which gives me 15 * 4 = 1 hour and 24 * 4 = 96 views to add in a linearlayout.

Comment: 96 views doesn't actually sound too bad.  That's actually what I'd do to start with if I were you.  The next step (if the performance turns out to be bad after all) would be to recycle views that aren't being displayed, or custom-draw the whole thing.